# Integration of Serialization and Deserialization in Builder Design Pattern using C#

Tags: c#, xml, design-patterns

I am implementing the [Builder Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) in order to generate a set of objects. These objects then have to be serialized to XML and deserialized from XML.

I know how to perform the serialization and deserialization however I am unsure how to integrate it into the design pattern.

For example suppose my code uses the builder to create products foo and bar. My first thought is to put a serialize function on each one because each product knows what to serialize.

My next thought was to put the deserialization in the Director or the ConcreteBuilder.

What I don't like about this is that the serialization and deserialization functions will be in different places - one in the file for the declaration of the foo and bar objects and the other in the files for something else. I am worried that they might end up becoming out of sync with each other as I work on the product classes.

My final thought was for the Director or ConcreteBuilder to perform the serialization and deserialization. What I don't like about that is the products then have to know which builder was used or know who the Director is.

To clarify - there are two situations where a product can be created:

1. User clicks on a button in the user interface
2. User loads a XML project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My current solution is to have the Product perform the serialization and the ConcreteBuilder perform the deserialization, then put both the Product and it's ConcreteBuilder declarations into the same source file.

Although the task is spread across two classes it is at least kept together in one file.

Any better solutions are appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Can you not simply have a static serialize/deserialize class and create a generic method that can take any type of object?  Isn't the pattern simply for building the objects?  You can then serialize as you wish?

Something like:

```
public static string Serialize<T>(T data)
    {
       XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
       StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
       xmlSerializer.Serialize(sw, data);
       return sw.ToString();

    }
```

Comment: Good idea, however I perform the XML serialization and deserialization manually because I kept running into too many limitations with the automatic method. I also need to trigger events after deserialization and set flags relating to the state of the user's project.